# Convert Json dateTime to String in JAVA

Tags: java, mysql, json, datetime

I have:
CreatedTime TIMESTAMP,
UpdatedTime TIMESTAMP,
Status Varchar,
AutoID columns

in mysql. Through my service i got the following json format.

```
 {
        "CreatedTime": "\/Date(1457646424000)\/",
        "UpdatedTime": "\/Date(1457647761000)\/",
        "Status": "Open",
        "AutoID": 1
 }
```

I'm trying to convert the CreatedTime and UpdatedTime like below:

```
public String ConvertJsonDateTime(String jsondate)
{
    if (jsondate != "" && !jsondate.equals("") && jsondate != null && jsondate != "null") {
        jsondate = jsondate.replace("/Date(", "").replace(")/", "");
        long time = Long.parseLong(jsondate);
        Date d = new Date(time);
        return new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss").format(d).toString();
    } else {
        return "";
    }
}
```

But it returns the wrong details. for example in Table the `CreatedTime` is `2016-03-10 14:47:04` but the function `ConvertJsonDateTime` returns as `2016-03-11 03:17:04`. How can i fix this one?

Comment: Probably you have to set the correct `TimeZone` for your `SimpleDateFormat`

Comment: `jsondate!=""` -> never comapre strings in Java using `==` or `!=`: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java And place `jsondate!=null` left-most in your expression: if it is null, `!jsondate.equals("")` will throw a NPE

Answer (score 0):

you need to set the correct timezone

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
sdf.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT")); // GMT or any timezone
```

also, as Bart says, you NEVER compare strings using `==` or `!=`, ALWAYS use `equals()`